# Getting current server name for URL build XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am trying to build a URL for my XPages application,but having problem geting the current server name, can anyone help me with these?

```
RT.appendText("http://localhost/" +dbname+"/store.xsp?documentId="+UNID+"&action=openDocument")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get the server part from the url

```
context.getUrl().toString().split(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI())[0]
```

I got this string from
http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/url.xsp

Comment: I see the point Frantisek it was never meant to be in someones code I hope. only as an Oneliner code example.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to handle HTTPS too:

```
var url = context.getUrl();
url.getScheme() + "://" + url.getHost()
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are actually looking for the server host name (which is part of the URL) and not the Domino server name, then you can do the following:

```
return context.getUrl().toString().split(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getRequestURI())[0]
```

David Leedy has created a [XPages URL cheatsheet](http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/url.xsp) with more details on URL handling.